# Why is my internet, that I get from a Wi-fi Extender and a Wi-fi Hotspot, both connected to an electric socket, not working?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

There is a house in which there is an internet connection from a cable (People get internet connection in our village from a cable that is under the ground...) going to 2 routers.
A cable from one of those routers is going to a device that is connected to an electric socket (Wi-Fi Extender) that is in that house.

Another device (Wi-Fi Hotspot) is connected to an electric socket in another house, in which I live and from which I get internet connection on my phone and on my laptop.

The distance between those two houses is like 20-30 metres.

It has worked fine for the last 7 months.

It stopped working today for some reason and I don't know why.

When I try to connect to internet with my Android phone it says that "It was not possible to assign an IP address."

The people who live in the first house have no problem and their internet works fine.

What can be the problem?

On both devices there is a button called "PAIR" to pair those 2 devices - Wi-Fi Extender in the first house with the Wi-Fi Hotspot in my house. Do I have to press those 2 buttons within 60 seconds on both devices, so that they pair up?

These are those two devices that I am using:

The smaller device is in the first house and the bigger device is in my house.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-LINK-TL-WPA4220KIT-Powerline-Configuration-Smartphone/dp/B00DHB2T44/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=TP-Link+TL-WPA4220&qid=1571068399&sr=8-4

Comment: It is possible that something about the electrical circuitry between the houses changed. Temporarily connect the electric socket extender in the "other" house to a circuit in the "same" house and see if it works

Comment: Which one do you call "Wi-Fi extender" and which one is "Wi-Fi hotspot"? From the link you gave, only the larger device has Wi-Fi at all – the other is wired Ethernet only.

Comment: Do you have the TP-Link tpPLC software (or the open-plc-utils package) installed on any computer, on either side? Does it detect both devices?

Comment: PLCs sometimes have issues but usually disconnecting from the outlet, waiting a few seconds and reconnecting is enough.

Comment: @grawity : The smaller device is in the first house and yes, an Ethernet cable from a router is connected to it. The bigger device is in my house and it is for creating a Wi-Fi nerwork in my house. Those 2 devices communicate with each other wirelessly.

Comment: No they don't. They communicate through the mains / power lines (Homeplug AV).

Answer (score 0):

So, eventually the ethernet cable was the cause of the problem. 
I replaced it with a new cable and now it all works flawlessly! 
:-)